# Has the Rep Limit Cap been revoked?

Tags: support, reputation

So I've hit the 200 cap a few times now, but today I logged in to find this:

[image]

[image]

What's the dealio, here? Has the rep been adjusted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the respective page in the [help center](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), it says:

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day from any combination of the activities below. Bounty awards, **accepted answers**, and association bonuses are not subject to the daily reputation limit.

And in fact you have an accepted answer in [your reputation changes](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/6306/john-smith-optional?tab=reputation) this day, that's why you're over 200 (and could as well have had another 5 points till the limit).

Comment: Ahhhh, that answers it then! Thanks.